# android app go to sleep mode when running on background

Tags: android, background, sleep

could my app does not use power and data when running on the background?

my app is native app and i want my app does not need run when on the background. But after I test use software LittleEye, my app consump power, memory, and data when running on background. How the way my app go to sleep when running on the background? (for prevent battery drain)

Answer (score 0):

In Android an app is not automatically killed when in background. It remains in the background stack. You need to stop doing background work as soon as your app goes to background. Use the onPause/onStop methods of activity lifecycle to handle application's processing when it is in background. If you are using android services in background you can stop/unbind them to avoid unneeded battery use.